# Postgres database missing after rails crash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

My rails app crashed and when I attempted to restart the server and connect I kept seeing:

```
$ psql
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I following the instructions in many different questions, reinstalling postgres, updating brew, etc. and nothing was working.  The only file I removed was the `postmaster.pid` file from `/usr/local/var/postgres`.  When I looked in the `server.log` file I saw I was using the wrong version of postgres and that the data directory was for another version.

I installed the older version and when I run `psql` it cannot find my database.  The only available databases are `postgres`, `template0`, and `template1`

**Am I missing something or did I manage to delete all my data?**

Comment: It doesn't look that you don't have expected database. It mostly looks like your server is down. Have you tried to restart your postgres? Can you provide an output?

Answer (score 0):

If, when you reinstalled Postgres, you made a major database version change, your database will be gone. Perhaps [this](https://gist.github.com/olivierlacan/e1bf5c34bc9f82e06bc0) will help you migrate your old data to your new running postgres instance.